# Creating index in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

## System

[image]

I have not created any bucket so started creating bucket.

[image]

Bucket configuration is listed below.

[image]

I added a document
[image]

Now i tried to run n1ql command and it give me following error.

```js
[
  {
    "code": 4000,
    "msg": "No index available on keyspace `default`:`test` that matches your query. Use CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `default`:`test` to create a primary index, or check that your expected index is online.",
    "query": "select * from test;"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. No indexes are created automatically in Couchbase, not even a primary index.

You can create a primary index with:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `test`
```

That's enough to make your query work. With a single document, it won't be too slow. But in production, you'll need to create indexes that are better tailored to your queries (just like in a relational database).

I recommend checking out the [documentation to learn more about indexes](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/indexing-and-query-perf.html).

Another tool that can be helpful is the [Index Advisor](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/guides/index-advisor.html). It can recommend better indexes, based on your query. Click the "Advice" button in Query Workbench to try it out.